# Debian 11 - LibreOffice can print, but okular can't?

Tags: cups, okular

I'm running Debian 11 with KDE, and I use LibreOffice 7.3, Okular 20.12.3 and CUPS 2.3.3; I do have `printer-driver-cups-pdf` installed as well. I can print documents from LibreOffice and from the browser (Firefox 111.0.1), but if I try to print from Okular, nothing happens: nothing shows up in the print queue in CUPS, nothing in the logs. I have disabled apparmor, just to see if it makes a difference, but it doesn't.

I've run out of ideas for what to try and where to look - how can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=334631

Comment: That was exactly it! Thx

Comment: You can answer your own question now. Make sure to describe all the steps and add the source.